# How to Check Out Document Remotely

Tags: 2013, development, client-object-model, client

I am trying to check out a file remotely using the `Sharepoint` libraries:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

public void CheckOutFile()
{
    // Set the context (URL) of the site 
    var cc = new ClientContext("http://MainSite/MySite");
    var file = cc.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/DocumentLibraryName/Document%20Name.docx");
    file.CheckOut();
    cc.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

But when my code reaches the `ExecuteQuery` line, I am seeing this error:

> "Value does not fall within the expected range."

I also tried this:

```
var cc = new ClientContext("http://MainSite/");
var file = cc.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/MySite/DocumentLibraryName/Document%20Name.docx");
```

But then I got another error:

> "The URL MySite/DocumentLibraryName/Document%20Name.docx is invalid.  It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web."

Can someone please point me in the right direction with this? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are close to the right point. In your first code-snippet you didn't provide a server-relative url for GetFileByServerRelativeUrl() (the "/MySite" part is missing). In your second snippet you do specifiy the server-relative url, but you're in the context of the RootWeb (this time the "/MySite" part is missing at new ClientContext().
Mixing it all together, following code should work for you:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

public void CheckOutFile()
{
    // Set the context (URL) of the site 
    var cc = new ClientContext("http://MainSite/MySite");
    var file = cc.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/MySite/DocumentLibraryName/Document%20Name.docx");
    file.CheckOut();
    cc.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If I am not wrong then I guess `MySite` in your url means `/sites/yoursitename/`. If its not like this then you must use.

So your line will be

```
var file = cc.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/MySite/DocumentLibraryName/Document%20Name.docx");
```

Instead of

```
var file = cc.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/MySite/DocumentLibraryName/Document%20Name.docx");
```

Also your `ClientContext` Line should be

```
var cc = new ClientContext("http://MainSite/sites/yoursite");
```

as you have mentioned in your first code.